# How do I index a numpy array of zeroes with a boolean datatype to True?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array

So I'm recreating a Matlab project they made last year, part of which involves creating mask that pull out the RGB bands. 
They did this by an array of logical zeroes.

```
GMask_Whole = false(ROWS,COLS);
```

which I reconstructed as a numpy array.

```
self.green_mask_whole=np.zeros((self.rows, self.columns), dtype=bool)
```

The next part I can't for the life of me figure out how to do with numpy:

```
GMask_Whole(1:2:end,2:2:end) = true;
```

I've yet to find a numpy equivalent action. any Ideas?

btw, if your curious about what this is doing:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter

edit:
things I've tried:

```
wut(1:3:end, 1:2:end) = true
wut([1:3:end], [1:2:end]) = true
wut([1:3], [1:2]) = true
wut([1:3], [1:2]) = True
wut(slice(1:3), slice(1:2)) = True
```

Comment: editing my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate Matlab's

```
GMask_Whole(1:2:end,2:2:end) = true;
```

to python by

```
green_mask_whole[::2,1::2] = True
```

(assuming `green_mask_whole` is a numpy array)

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` can do slicing more or less as in Matlab, but the synax is a little bit different. In `numpy`, the order is `[begin:end:step]` and it is possible to leave both `begin`, `end` and `step` empty, which will give them their default values *first element*, *last element* and *step size 1* respectively.

Further, `numpy´ has a nice system of 'broad casting' which allows a single value (or row/column) be repeated to make a new array of the same size as another. This makes it possible to assign a single value to a whole array.

Thus, in the current case, it is possible to do

```
self.green_mask_whole=np.zeros((self.rows, self.columns), dtype=bool)
self.green_mask_whole[::2,1::2] = True
```